# Tensorflow: item assignment not supported, other solutions?

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code snippet. I sample one item per row from a matrix. This item should be 1, while the others are zero. Is there an elegant solutions for this in TensorFlow

```
# Some example data
weights = tf.random_uniform([10,3], minval=0, maxval=1)

# Sample from weights
id_x = tf.multinomial(tf.log(weights), 1)

# Build corresponding indices
ind_range = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(id_x)[0]), 1)
ind = tf.concat(1, [ind_range, tf.cast(id_x, dtype=tf.int32)])
gripper = tf.zeros([tf.shape(id_x)[0], 3])
gripper[ind] = 1

with tf.Session() as sess:
  x,y = sess.run([id_x,ind])

print x
print y
```

This snippet results in 'TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment'

Comment: that snippet works for me, you should include more information, like complete stack trace

Comment: sorry, the line with gripper[ind] was commented out, now fixed. Try again please

Comment: oh right....so Tensors are immutable, so you can't modify them. One solution is to use tf.Variable for gripper.